# Interpreting graph as a hash table (python dict)

Tags: python, graph, dictionary, hashmap

I understand simple directed graph interpretation like this:

```
graph = {1: [2], 2: [3], 3: [4, 5, 1], 4: [], 5: [4]}
#               1
#              / .
#             /   \
#            .     \
#       4--.3 ------.2
#        \  .
#         \ |
#          .5
```

But do not know how to interpret dict of dicts, such as:

```
{1: {2: 3, 3: 8, 5: -4}, 2: {4: 1, 5: 7}, 3: {2: 4}, 4: {1: 2, 3: -5}, 5: {4: 6}}
```

Is it weighted graph? How should I understand this kind of graphs write?

*If you decide to downvote this question, please leave a link with the corresponding article in a comment.*

Comment: Where did your dictionary structure come from? Either: **1)** you defined the structure yourself, and the question is moot, or **2)** someone else built the structure, and failed to document what it represented. Without having produced that structure, there is no way to _know_ how to interpret it. Closing as too localized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a directed graph with weighted edges. The following graph

[image: Weighted Digraph]

is represented as..

```
L = {'A': {'C':2, 'D':6}, 'B': {'D':8, 'A':3},
   'C': {'D':7, 'E':5}, 'D': {'E':-2}, 'E': {}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a weighted edge directed graph.  You can also use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) to visualize your particular data:

```
nestedg={1: {2: 3, 3: 8, 5: -4}, 
     2: {4: 1, 5: 7}, 
     3: {2: 4}, 
     4: {1: 2, 3: -5}, 
     5: {4: 6}}

with open('/tmp/graph.dot','w') as out:
    for line in ('digraph G {','size="16,16";','splines=true;'):
        out.write('{}\n'.format(line))  
    for start,d in nestedg.items():
        for end,weight in d.items():
              out.write('{} -> {} [ label="{}" ];\n'.format(start,end,weight))
    out.write('}\n')
```

Which produces this graphical representation:

[image]

You could use something like [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to navigate paths through it. An example use would be for routing with certain routes having a greater 'cost':

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        if start not in graph:
            return []
        paths = []
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
        return paths       

def min_path(graph, start, end):
    paths=find_all_paths(graph,start,end)
    mt=10**99
    mpath=[]
    print '\tAll paths from {} to {}: {}'.format(start,end,paths)
    for path in paths:
        t=sum(graph[i][j] for i,j in zip(path,path[1::]))
        print '\t\tevaluating: {}, cost: {}'.format(path, t)
        if t<mt: 
            mt=t
            mpath=path

    e1=' '.join('{}->{}:{}'.format(i,j,graph[i][j]) for i,j in zip(mpath,mpath[1::]))
    e2=str(sum(graph[i][j] for i,j in zip(mpath,mpath[1::])))
    print 'Best path: '+e1+'   Total: '+e2+'\n'  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nestedg={1: {2: 3, 3: 8, 5: -4}, 
         2: {4: 1, 5: 7}, 
         3: {2: 4}, 
         4: {1: 2, 3: -5}, 
         5: {4: 6}}

    min_path(nestedg,1,5)
    min_path(nestedg,1,4)
    min_path(nestedg,2,1)
```

Using your data, some example routes through the graph are:

```
    All paths from 1 to 5: [[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 2, 5], [1, 5]]
        evaluating: [1, 2, 5], cost: 10
        evaluating: [1, 3, 2, 5], cost: 19
        evaluating: [1, 5], cost: -4
Best path: 1->5:-4   Total: -4

    All paths from 1 to 4: [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 5, 4], [1, 5, 4]]
        evaluating: [1, 2, 4], cost: 4
        evaluating: [1, 2, 5, 4], cost: 16
        evaluating: [1, 3, 2, 4], cost: 13
        evaluating: [1, 3, 2, 5, 4], cost: 25
        evaluating: [1, 5, 4], cost: 2
Best path: 1->5:-4 5->4:6   Total: 2

    All paths from 2 to 1: [[2, 4, 1], [2, 5, 4, 1]]
        evaluating: [2, 4, 1], cost: 3
        evaluating: [2, 5, 4, 1], cost: 15
Best path: 2->4:1 4->1:2   Total: 3
```